# "The Azure Access Control service is unavailable" on Azure Sharepoint Farm via Oauth

Tags: 2013, azure, oauth

we are trying to evaluate integrating Sharepoint 2013 as a Data Source into our app, i.e. create a low trust app that receives a token from Sharepoint and makes further inquiries with that token. The app is hosted on a different server completely and actually being developed in a non-MS language.

So far we have

- created a Sharepoint 2013 Farm on Azure as outlined [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-sharepoint-farm-azure-preview/)
- created a Site Collection "site-collection" on that sharepoint
- added an OAuth application via AppRegNew.aspx
- given that application some permissions in AppInv.aspx

`<AppPermissionRequests>`

`<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />`

`<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web/list" Right="Write"/>`

`</AppPermissionRequests>`

At this point most of the OAuth workflow seems to be working:
When going to

```
http://sharepoint-url/_layouts/15/OAuthAuthorize.aspx?client_id=our-client-id&redirect_uri=https://our-redirect-uri&response_type=code&scope=List.Read&state=xyz...
```

we are prompted to log in (works) and prompted to authorize the app. However we are being redirected to:

```
https://redirect-uri?error=server%5Ferror&error%5Fdescription=The%20Azure%20Access%20Control%20service%20is%20unavailable%2E&state=xyz
```

Thus the error seems to be that "The Azure Access Control Service is unavailable".

As this error message seems pretty uncommon, we have taken to trying to establish some trust between the Azure Access Control Service and our Sharepoint farm by registering our sharepoint with ACS and exchanging certificates, as outlined [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22309.integrating-windows-live-id-google-and-facebook-accounts-with-sharepoint-2013-white-paper.aspx).

However this did not help at all, the error message persists. Is there some way we could further debug this? Is the problem with our sharepoint that really can't reach ACS or is there some configuration error?

Thanks for reading this far, I hope someone can shed some light onto this.